# After running "Summarywriter",there is on folder called logs

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am learning TensorBoard. After running the code (as follows), it did not create a the `logs` folder. How to deal with it?

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

writer = SummaryWriter('logs')
# writer.add_image()

for i in range(100):
    writer.add_scalar("y=x", i, i)

writer.close()
```